# Refresh Excel VBA Function Results

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

How can I get a user-defined function to re-evaluate itself based on changed data in the spreadsheet?

I tried **<kbd>F9</kbd>** and **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>**.

The only thing that seems to work is editing the cell with the function call and then pressing Enter.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You should use `Application.Volatile` in the top of your function:

```
Function doubleMe(d)
    Application.Volatile
    doubleMe = d * 2
End Function
```

It will then reevaluate whenever the workbook changes (if your calculation is set to automatic).

Comment: Thanks, just been bashing my head against a desk over this. Should point out though that in Excel 2010, you need to pass True to Application.Volatile, i.e. `Application.Volatile True`.

Comment: @mdm Thanks for the info on the True!!  Needed this also for a custom worksheet function in Excel 2013!!

Comment: this works when I change the value of a cell, but I have a function that sums cells based on fill color and this doesn't update the function when I change the cell's fill color, I have to retype the value.  can I have the worksheet live update as I change Fill Color?

Comment: @ChrisL Did you find a solution for your use case with the calculation based on fill color? Appreciate your solution.

Comment: @smartini I never continued looking for a solution.  I wasn't using my fill color function often enough for it to matter.  I was hoping for a quick answer to my comment 4 years ago but it never came.  Maybe best to start a new question.  If you do, hit me up with a comment here so I can follow it.

Answer (score 46):

Some more information on the F9 keyboard shortcuts for calculation in Excel

- <kbd>F9</kbd>                Recalculates all worksheets in all open workbooks
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F9</kbd>          Recalculates the active worksheet
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F9</kbd>       Recalculates all worksheets in all open workbooks (Full recalculation)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F9</kbd> Rebuilds the dependency tree and does a full recalculation

Answer (score 18):

Okay, found this one myself.  You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to accomplish this.

Comment: This is your only option if you have Excel 2007 seeing as the `Application.Volatile` method was added in Office 2010.

Answer (score 12):

If you include ALL references to the spreadsheet data in the UDF parameter list, Excel will recalculate your function whenever the referenced data changes:

```
Public Function doubleMe(d As Variant)
    doubleMe = d * 2
End Function
```

You can also use `Application.Volatile`, but this has the disadvantage of making your UDF always recalculate - even when it does not need to because the referenced data has not changed.

```
Public Function doubleMe()
    Application.Volatile
    doubleMe = Worksheets("Fred").Range("A1") * 2
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it best to only update the calculation when a specific cell is changed. Here is an example VBA code to place in the "Worksheet" "Change" event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F3")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.CalculateFull
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To switch to Automatic:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

To switch to Manual:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Answer (score 1):

This refreshes the calculation better than `Range(A:B).Calculate`:

```
Public Sub UpdateMyFunctions()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Assume the functions are in this range A1:B10.
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B10")

    For Each rng In myRange
        rng.Formula = rng.Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Application.Volatile` doesn't work for recalculating a formula with my own function inside. I use the following function:
`Application.CalculateFull`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub UpdateMyFunctions()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    'Considering The Functions are in Range A1:B10
    Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B10")

    For Each rng In myRange
        rng.Formula = rng.Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain the code a bit. It would increase the usefullness quite a lot.

Comment: rng.Formula = rng.Formula is the same as entering a cell and pressing enter again. It forces Excel to calculate the cell again - including any custom functions.