# User defined function does not update on excel

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refresh Excel VBA Function Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/refresh-excel-vba-function-results)

I have simple function in excel:

```
Function Test() As String

    Test = Now

End Function
```

and I am able to use it as:

[image]

Now why is it that when I press the button:

[image]

the value does not update !?

For example if I have a cell with the formula `=Rand()` every time I click the calculate value I will get a different number. How can I make my custom function behave the same way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `application.volatile` to the job

Btw, `now()` is available as an excel function

Comment: What is the duff? thanks for the help. I just use the now example to illustrate my problem. My real function reads a value from a web service on the internet...

Comment: I just placed Application.volatile on the first line of the function and it worked. Thanks!