# Worksheet_Change determine value not content

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to detect if there are changes in a cell value, not particularly the cell contents. I have found multiple solutions to find out if a cell contents has changed, but it does not work when a cell is equal to another cell.

For example, I have cell A1 set to equal B1 and then B1 has a formula that calls in multiple other cells, so I am not able to go back to the beginning and determine whether the cell has changed from that. It needs to come directly from A1.

This is one of the examples I found on this site, but does not determine if the value of A1 has changed, just whether the contents has changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 1 Then
     Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Date
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406628/vba-code-doesnt-run-when-cell-is-changed-by-a-formula/11409569#11409569)?

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` event macro is not triggered when a value returned by a formula changes.

Answer (score 0):

The function application.volatile TRUE at the top of your sub will make your sub calculate each time any value in Excel changes. So then you need a global variable which stores the last-known value of your specified range, and any time the sub runs, start with an

```
If new_cell_value <> stored_global_variable then...
```

and close with

```
    stored_global_variable = new_cell value'
End If
```

See here for further info [h/t to vzczc for the original answer and method]: [Refresh Excel VBA Function Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/refresh-excel-vba-function-results)

Comment: It still doesn't work between sheets. If I change something on sheet 1 that causes changes on sheet 2, it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Could you post your changes to your code (edit into your original q) and an example of the data used to get a failing result?