# Update Cell function after Value Change

Tags: excel, vba, function, module

I have a VBA that counts the number of COLORED CELLS. The VBA module is asigned to a cell. But, the function only runs when the i click on the cell function and press ENTER. Changing a cell value does not run the function automatically. 
 AUTOMATIC UPDATE of formulas are enabled in options too.

Here's my VBA:

```html
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range, Optional SUM As Boolean)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim vResult
lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
If SUM = True Then
For Each rCell In rRange
If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
End If
Next rCell
Else
For Each rCell In rRange
If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
vResult = 1 + vResult
End If
Next rCell
End If
ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

and Im calling this module using the worksheet command : =ColorFunction(J70,$B$3:$BV$66)

Any help??
 Thanx

Answer (score 0):

you could use a little workaround

in the relevant sheet code pane place the following code

```
Option Explicit

Dim myColor As Long '<--| variable to store the "preceeding" color

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim coloredRng As Range

    If myColor > 0 Then '<--| if a "colored" cell had been selected in the "preceeding" selection, then store its color
        Me.Calculate '<--| trigger calculation and, by its effects, all functions with 'Application.Volatile'
        myColor = 0 '<--| reset "preceeding" color to zero. it'll be set to a vaild color if user has currently selected a "colored" cell
    End If

    Set coloredRng = Range("J70:J73") '<--| set the range whose color change must "trigger" 'ColorFunction()' (change "J70:J73" to your actual "colored" cells addresses)
    If Not Intersect(Target, coloredRng) Is Nothing Then myColor = Target.Interior.Color '<--| if current selection belongs to the "colored" range then store its color to trigger 'ColorFunction()' cells as soon as the user leaves the current selection
End Sub
```

this will actually trigger all `ColorFunction()` function after the users has:

- changed the color of a *valid* cell (one of those you list in `coloredRng`)
- left the changed colored cell

so you'll experience a little delay but it'll work

Comment: @KADAragorn, did you get through it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set `Application.Volatile`.

Further details here:

[Refresh Excel VBA Function Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/refresh-excel-vba-function-results)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Application.Valatile only works when a VALUE a changed. :(  Not when the background Cell color changes.. Any fix for that?
 I dont even mind if there is a button to update the cells..

Comment: Did you try these:
Ctrl+Alt+ F9 Recalculates all worksheets in all open workbooks (Full recalculation)
Shift + Ctrl+Alt+ F9 Rebuilds the dependency tree and does a full recalculation