# Refreshing a VBA function not only with value changes (Also colors etc...)

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to refresh a cell function that returns the colorindex of a cell.

```
Function doubled(RA As Range)

Application.Volatile
doubled = RA.Font.ColorIndex

End Function
```

I have seen this answer but it only updates for values : [Refresh Excel VBA Function Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/refresh-excel-vba-function-results)

Comment: You can't. Changing colours will not trigger a recalculation, so you'd have to use something like a timer to recalculate everything periodically, which would be annoying at best. Best solution in my opinion is to rethink your entire approach to whatever you think you need this for. ;)

Comment: @Rory thanks, At least I know that Application.volatile brought me as far as possible for a clean code :)